# Fastest way to set a single value in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe where I need to iteratively perform some calculations and set a subset of the dataframe, as illustrated in the example below. The example below has index 1000 x 100, but in my real dataset, the [100] isn't fixed. Sometimes there are more, sometimes less. The other complication is that on my real dataset, `df.loc[0]._is_view` returns False (not sure why).

So even though the first option below `df.loc[0, 'C']` is faster, I couldn't really use it. I've been using the second option `df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('A') == 0, 'C']`, which takes twice as long.

Does anyone know of a faster way to edit a subset of the dataframe?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, size=(100000, 2)),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [list(range(1000)), list(range(100))], names=["A", "B"]
    ),
    columns=["C", "D"],
)

%%timeit
df.loc[0, 'C'] = 1.
870 µs ± 91.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('A') == 0, 'C'] = 1.
1.41 ms ± 4.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `loc` which, in most cases, should be faster is Pandas [at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) property:

```py
%%timeit
df.loc[0, 'C'] = 1
171 µs ± 31.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Whereas:

```py
%%timeit
df.at[0, 'C'] = 1
153 µs ± 3.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```